# Show previous,current and next stage in statusbar for Odoo v10?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, statusbar, odoo-10, odoo

How to show current,previous and next stage in status bar?

**My python code below :**

```
workflow_stage = fields.Many2one('stage.name', group_expand='_operation_process_stage_ids'
                             ,domain="[('stage_name', '=', work_flow_type)]")
```

**Xml code:**

```
<field name="workflow_stage" domain="[('stage_name', '=', workflow_stage)]"
                           widget="statusbar" options="{'fold_field': 'fold'}"/>
```

Comment: Add a sequence field ( fields.Integer ) in the stage.name model, you dont need the domain, you will see the status bar with all the states ordered

Comment: ok, but how to show previous, current and next stages in status bar ??